# Getting error in c++ STL in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, visual-studio-2015

I have upgrade projects from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015. In 2010 everything works fine, but in 2015 I get compiler errors which is related to C++11 STL.
I have tried to understand and search but did not get clear under standing what has changed in C++.
I am getting error at this line

```
`pair<DispatchMap::iterator, bool> res(m_dispatchMap.insert(make_pair(entry->GetHandle(), _af_new CallbackMap(1, entry))));`
```

error is.

```
Error C2664 'void std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>)':
 cannot convert argument 1
 from 'std::pair<void *,std::list<DispatchThread::CallbackEntryBasePtr,std::allocator<_Ty>> >'
 to 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&'
```

Is something has changed in C++11 map ?

It would be great if I will get clear understanding!!

Comment: One change is that you have to use `const_iterator` to access keys in a `std::map` or data in a `std::set`.  You cannot declare a non-const `iterator` to these items.  Don't know if this is the reason for your error, but C+11 enforces the `const`-ness of the map and set data.

Comment: Please can you split the lines somewhere?  It's very hard to read such long lines.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You don't have to use a `const_iterator` for a `map` or `set`.  The _Key_ in the `map` is `const`, so you can't change it, but you can have normal `iterators` into them (from which you can change the value).

Comment: If you attempt to change the key in a map or set, the 2010 didn't enforce this.  You could declare non-const iterators and mess up maps and sets internals in 2010.  Now it is not allowed in 2015.  That is what I encountered when porting code from 2010 to 2015.

Comment: Hi All,  I have added code snippet regarding second error please have look at the code,

Comment: @MehulDonga: Your `ThreadPairData` typedef has a `Test` object as the first type of the inner `pair` but you're giving it a `Test *` instead. Is this your actual code? Why are you using `new`? Do you like memory leaks?

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes this is my code, I have written this code to generate error.

Comment: Thank you Blastfurnace second error resolves but still getting first error

Comment: In VC++ 2015 we need to type cast argument I have made change in code working fine. Changed code =                        pair<DispatchMap::iterator, bool> res(m_dispatchMap.insert(make_pair(entry->GetHandle(), (CallbackMapPtr)_bf_new CallbackMap(1, entry))));

Answer (score 1):

In the first error, `entry->GetHandle()` returns a `void *`, which is not the key type of the map you're storing in to.  You'll either need to change the type that GetHandle returns or cast the `void *` to the correct const type.

The second error is because `GetThreadId` is returning an `unsigned int`, but your map wants a `DWORD` (which is an `unsigned long`).  You'll need to change the return type, cast, or change the type in the map to fix it.